# Prevent concurrent callback code from running twice

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code run inside a new thread.

```
private class SaveUserTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
            DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(LoginActivity.this);
            dbHandler.createUser(users[0]);
            return null;
        }

}
```

The code that construct it and run it is inside a callback method.

```
private class GraphCallbackHandler implements Request.GraphUserCallback {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser gUser, Response response) {
            if (gUser != null) {
                id = gUser.getId().trim();
                DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(
                        LoginActivity.this);
        if (!dbHandler.isFacebookIdAlreadyStored(id)) {
                    SaveUserTask suTask = new SaveUserTask();
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(gUser.getUsername().trim());
            user.setFacebookId(id);
            if (email != null)
            user.setEmail(emailStr.trim());
            suTask.execute(user);
       }
    }
```

It looks as if that callback method is being called twice causing two identical rows to be inserted into the table. Is there any way to prevent this either by preventing the callback method from being called twice (which to me seems quite unlikely to achieve) or stopping the background task from running twice?

Comment: Why don't you put debug in the API. And have look at debug trace. You will know from where it gets call

Comment: I have tried that. This can sometimes happen. It's actually caused by the system executing the UI twice. As it is the system doing the job, it leaves me with little choice as to preventing the code from repeatedly being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this steps:

1. Move your user existance check code to your `doInBackground` method.
2. set `doInBackground` method code `synchronized` by an `Object` LOCK.

or you can store your saved users to an object like `HashSet` inside memory and check existance before inserting to db.

Note that some where of working with database in cases like that must be thread safe or synchronized. Otherwise, you may have such problems like this.

Comment: I know that this is a thread problem but I still haven't acquired concurrent thinking in Java. Thanks for your answer. I'll try it and if it works, set your answer as an accepted one.

Comment: It works, Yavari. You've saved me hours of work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a typical race condition if `onCompleted` called twice in short period of time:
Happy path:

1. Check user doesn't exist (thread1)
2. Launch insert in another thread (thread1)
3. Do insert (thread2)
4. Check user doesn't exist (thread1) -> do nothing

and it could work in another order, as threads work in parallel:

1. Check user doesn't exist (thread1)
2. Launch insert in another thread (thread1)
3. Check user doesn't exist (thread1)
4. Launch insert in another thread (thread1)
5. Do insert (thread2)
6. Do insert (thread3)

I think the best solution is to move (or copy) the check so that the async operation should do the check to make the operation [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).